# LINQ projection to presentation model

Tags: linq, projection

I'm pretty new to LINQ and a lot of modern data-driven application design techniques in general, so this may be a pretty basic question.

I'm trying to create a projection of a couple different Entity Framework entities to a simple presentation model. Let's say I have the entites Parent (properties are ID, Name, Age) and Child (properties are ID, Name, Age, with a reference to a Parent). I want to project these to PresentationParent and PresentationChild, where all the properties are the same, but PresentationParent has a List. How would I do this in LINQ?

```
from p in entities.Parent
select new PresentationParent
{
    ID = p.ID,
    Name = p.Name,
    Age = p.Age,
    Children = [[?? What goes here ??]]
}
```

Is this on the right track at all? I can only seem to find examples of simple, flat projections.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
from p in entities.Parent
select new PresentationParent {
    ID = p.ID,
    Name = p.Name,
    Age = p.Age,
    Children = (from c in entities.Child
                where c.Parent == p
                select new PresentationChild {
                    ID = c.ID,
                    Name = c.Name,
                    Age = c.Age
                }).ToList()
}
```

However, your entities should come pre-configured with the necessary foreign key relationships already, so you could do something like this:

```
from p in entities.Parent
select new PresentationParent {
    ID = p.ID,
    Name = p.Name,
    Age = p.Age,
    Children = p.Children.ToList()
}
```

Of course, that would return all the properties of each child, so you might want to project the children anyway:

```
from p in entities.Parent
select new PresentationParent {
    ID = p.ID,
    Name = p.Name,
    Age = p.Age,
    Children = (from c in p.Children
                select new PresentationChild {
                    ID = c.ID,
                    Name = c.Name,
                    Age = c.Age
                }).ToList()
}
```

Comment: This compiles but  fails when you try to enumerate the result set - it complains that LINQ to Entities "does not recognize" the ToList method, and "this method cannot be translated into a store expression." It works if I use LINQ to SQL instead of EF though.

Comment: I'm not in a position to try this myself right now, but you could try moving the `ToList` method to enclose the entire outer query instead. That should give the L2E provider more flexibility to translate the query into valid SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative, if the relationship isn't set up enough to have the accessor available:

```
from p in entities.Parent
from c in entities.Children on p.ID equals c.parentID into children
select new PresentationParent
{
    ID = p.ID,
    Name = p.Name,
    Age = p.Age,
    Children = children.ToList()
}
```

Comment: Won't children.ToList() create a list of Child objects, not PresentationChild objects?